# How can I create an application/json HTTPResponse in actix?

Tags: rust, rust-actix

In the `example` [section](https://github.com/actix/examples/blob/18b75bc6c6d536164b340fbdd2a8e1d14afd1edb/basics/src/main.rs#L77-L79), they use:

```
HttpResponse::Ok()
    .content_type("text/plain")
    .body(format!("Hello {}!", req.match_info().get("name").unwrap()))
```

Yet I don't like to hardcode my `content-type` since there's a nice [class](https://github.com/actix/actix-web/blob/f5bec968c754d7777fa69a1258c49f6f3ca07cbd/src/header/common/content_type.rs#L53C1-L56) that shows I can use an enum for the `json` response:

```
let mut builder = HttpResponse::Ok();
builder.set(ContentType(TEXT_HTML));
```

The problem is that I want to set the response's body as well. How can I do it in `builder` above?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Same as in first example, just replace .content_type() with .set()